# df.to_sql raises ValueError("Empty table or column name specified")

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

`list(df)` retrieves the column headers of a  `df` dataframe. `headers_list` retrieves the existing column headers of an existing `438393848` table. What I am trying to do is to `DROP` the column headers of the `438393848` table that do not exist in the `df` and thereafter use the `to_sql` method to push the `df` dataframe into the `438393848` SQLite database. However, `df.to_sql` raises ValueError("Empty table or column name specified").

```
with conn:
        c.execute(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '438393848' ({list(df)[0]})")
        try:
            for header in list(df)[1:]:
                c.execute(f"ALTER TABLE '438393848' ADD COLUMN {header}")
        except:
               pass
        colnames = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM '438393848'").description
        headers_list = list(map(lambda x: x[0], colnames))
        for column in headers_list:
            if column not in list(df):
                c.execute(f"ALTER TABLE '438393848' DROP COLUMN {column}")
        colnamesnew = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM '438393848'").description
    df.to_sql('438393848', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

For context, I editted the `df` dataframe in a different set of code, which makes `df` not be in sync with the SQLite table `438393848`. What I want to do is to use this set of code to update the columns of my table `438393848` so that the `df` can be pushed to the SQLite table now that the columns are matching. After running the code once, by printing the table `438393848`, the column is `DROP`ed and in accordance to the column headers of the dataframe `df`.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Try `print(headers_list)` before you loop with `for column in headers_list:`. What does it print?

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading the df.to_sql documentation, the `if_exists=replace` parameter drops the table and replaces the table with an entirely new data set, which is `df` in this case. Hence, there is no need for the above code to replace the column header names.